# How to find duplicates in a linkedlist - java

Tags: java

How would you go about looking through a linkedlist to find the first duplicate object in the list, can it be done with nested for loops like with an array?

Comment: Yes, of course you can

Comment: Faster to sort it first.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new HashMap. Iterate your list and add objects from it to a HashMap mapping them to Boolean.TRUE for example. Before adding an object to the HashMap, check if it's already in the HashMap. If it is already present - this is the first duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You could also add elements to a HashSet until you come across the first duplicate:

```
Set<YourObject> set = new HashSet<YourObject>();
for (YourObject obj : yourList) {
    if (!set.add(obj)) {  // check if already existed in the set
        return obj;   // found the duplicate
    }
}
```

Should be more efficient than nested loops ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the first and last index of your object in the list. If the substraction of both is inferior than 0, that means you have a duplicate.

```
LinkedList<String> s = new LinkedList<>();
/*
 * Fill it here
 */ 
for(String str : s){
    if(linkedList.indexOf(str) - linkedList.lastIndexOf(str) < 0){
        System.out.println("First duplicate is: " + str);
        break;
     }
}
```

Comment: I think i found an issue using your method. I am effectively looking through a hand of cards, and so even though the cards have identical values they aren't identical objects. So I guess i should specify that i need to find cards with duplicate values in the linkedlist, not duplicate objects, but thanks for helping me clearly identify the problem

Comment: @user3074140 If you redefined your equals method, that should work. However, note that is implementation is not very efficient.